# Python create key for top level and nested dictionary at the same time

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a  a dictionary populated with keys whose values are dictionaries. How would I go about creating a both a key for the top level dictionary and the nested dictionary at the same time. Something like the following:

```
famCountDictofDicts = {"one": {"oneA": 1, "oneB": 2, "oneC": 3}, "two": {"twoA": 1, "twoB": 2, "twoC": 3}}

famCountDictofDicts 
{'one': {'oneA': 1, 'oneB': 2, 'oneC': 3},
 'two': {'twoA': 1, 'twoB': 2, 'twoC': 3}}

famCountDictofDicts["three"]["threeA"] = 1

famCountDictofDicts
{'one': {'oneA': 1, 'oneB': 2, 'oneC': 3},
 'two': {'twoA': 1, 'twoB': 2, 'twoC': 3},
 'three': {'threeA': 1}}
```

As this does not work I figure I could create an empty key then populate it but am also unsure how to do that.

I am wanting to do this as I have a file list of dataframes and for each dataframe I need to store the value of certain variables but not all dataframes have the same variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by declaring your dictionary as a `defaultdict` of `dicts`. Like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict


famCountDictofDicts = {"one": {"oneA": 1, "oneB": 2, "oneC": 3}, "two": {"twoA": 1, "twoB": 2, "twoC": 3}}

famCountDictofDicts = defaultdict(dict, famCountDictofDicts)    
famCountDictofDicts["three"]["threeA"] = 1  # <- this now works
```

For more, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: This works perfectly. thank you! I just call `famCountDictofDicts = defaultdict(dict) `instead of `famCountDictofDicts = defaultdict(dict, famCountDictofDicts)`  as to begin with I have no predefined keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal you show in your code example, you could create the nested dict in the right side of the assignment like so:

```py
    famCountDictofDicts["three"] = {"threeA": 1}
```

Comment: I tried this but then each subsequent call overrides not appends the last one:    `famCountDictofDicts["three"] = {"threeB": 1}`  would just result in `{'one': {'oneA': 1, 'oneB': 2, 'oneC': 3},
 'two': {'twoA': 1, 'twoB': 2, 'twoC': 3},
 'three': {'threeB': 1}}`